# How to use background worker to loading a form? c#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

How to use background worker in loading a form after clicking a button? I'm gonna use it because my form takes around 20-30secs to load. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
What is your current attempt on solving the problem? Any short examples? Show us what you researched so far.

Comment: Everything UI specific belongs to the mainthread. If your Form takes to long to load put the things thats makes its load slow into a different thread not the loading itself. But be aware putting it into a different thread makes the form not usable earlier per se if the things that are loaded in the background are needed for the forms working.

Comment: I've watch tutorials. They're using progress bar, and as the progress bar reached 100% a message pop up saying "success". In my case, as the progress bar is working to get to 100% I want to load my form as the same time to minimize the waiting time in loading the form. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation class from a simple form project. I am using the synchronization context to marshall the progress updates to the UI thread. In the constructor it's getting the context for the current UI thread so it can be used in the background worker thread to provide status updates.

I've also shown you how to cancel a running background worker as well.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    SynchronizationContext _syncContext;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    private void btnLoadForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(HandleDoWork);
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(HandleWorkerCompleted);
        _worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(HandleProgressChanged);
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
        {
            _worker.CancelAsync();
        }
    }

    private void HandleDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // DO Any work to instantiate the form
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        if (_worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Form2 newForm = new Form2();
            newForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    private void HandleProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // DO Progress Bar Updates Here
        SendOrPostCallback callback = new SendOrPostCallback((o) =>
        {
            label1.Text = "This is my Async content";
        });
        _syncContext.Send(callback, null);
    }

    private void HandleWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // DO Any completed step items here
    }

}
```

Comment: Mr. Rob Stewart, thanks a lot..